# Sending one word at a time to cowsay

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I need to send each word from an existing txt file within my Ubuntu server to cowsay.
I would like to send one word at a time until the whole word txt file has been recited.

I have written the following script but I don't seem to see any result.

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
SCRIPT_PATH="/home/Class/gettysburg.txt"
read  $(<$SCRIPT_PATH)| while read line;
do
    for word in $line;
    do
        cowsay $word;
        echo $word;
    done;
done
```

Comment: Paste your code into https://shellcheck.net and fix errors and recommendations found. It seems like your close, except use `done < $SCRIPT_PATH` and skip `read (...)|`. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

To split the file into separate words and send it to any program one word at a time, use `cat filename | xargs -n1 command`. In your case:

```
cat /home/Class/gettysburg.txt | xargs -n1 cowsay
```

or, without `cat`:

```
< /home/Class/gettysburg.txt xargs -n1 cowsay
```